# How can I run a finished Selenium-RC project from command prompt?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I created a test case using selenium-RC with JAVA using Eclipse IDE and selenium jars.

The project is finished and running fine.

My question:

What is next? do i have to run the test case from Eclipse every time? or there are next steps?

I want to run this test on a scheduled manner every hour. I could do that if i could run it from a command prompt. Is there a way better that command prompt or it is enough?!

Answer (score 0):

Use Jenkins with testng 
set after test  to close the browser

```
@AfterSuite(alwaysRun = true)
 public void closeBrowser(WebDriver driver) {
    if (driver != null) {
      driver.close();
      driver.quit();
      driver = null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I know how to close the browser. My question is what should I do with the project. I want to run it from a command prompt. how can I do that?

Comment: you have Jenkins try to use it it is very simple

Comment: if you want to use command line java - jar (will run your main)